# in Yaml can I trigger a pipeline run at specific time?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline I Azure Devops which is triggered as below, however as well as triggering when develop is updated I also want it to trigger it at a specified time eg each night at 10pm...how can I accomplish this ?

```
trigger:
- develop
```

Comment: You should be looking into the Scheduled Triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#branch-considerations-for-scheduled-triggers

Answer (score 1):

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```